# Why would a PHP soap call work in Guzzle but not in SoapClient?

Tags: php, soap

Using the following Guzzle call I get a successful response:

```
$client = new Client();         
$body = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>             <soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">             <soap:Body>                 <GetAuthenticationToken xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">                     <username>'. config('services.tmw.username') .'</username>                     <password>'. config('services.tmw.username') .'</password>                     <applicationName>testing</applicationName>                 </GetAuthenticationToken>             </soap:Body>             </soap:Envelope>         ';

$wsdl = '*** MASKED URL ***Service.svc';         
$res = $client->request('POST', $wsdl, [
    'headers' => ['Content-Type' => 'text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'SOAPAction' => 'http://tempuri.org/IDRTrackWebService/GetAuthenticationToken'],             
    'body' => $body]);         
$body = $res->getBody();         
dd($body->getContents());
```

So thankfully that works but it would be much simpler to use SoapClient. So I did this:

```
$svcUrl = '---MASKED URL ---Service.svc';
$wsdl = '---MASKED URL ---Service.svc?wsdl';

        $client = new \SoapClient($wsdl, array('trace' => 1));
        $params = new \stdClass();
        $params->username = 'username';
        $params->password = 'password';
        $params->applicationName = 'testing';
    
        $result =  $client->__soapCall('GetAuthenticationToken', ['GetAuthenticationToken' => $params]);
        dd($result);
```

I have tested with and without the ?wsdl and I get the same response:

SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't load from '---MASKED URL ---Service.svc?wsdl' : failed to load external entity "---MASKED URL ---Service.svc?wsdl"

If I got to the url without the ?wsdl it shows me instructions, and if I go to the url with the ?wsdl it shows me the full xml.

I also validated that the wsdl:service => port => soap:address is the same as the $svcUrl.
finalluy I have the call setup and running in SoapUI just fine as well.

I am losing my mind since this should just work.  Any ideas?  TIA.

Comment: Try downloading the WSDL file. Then access it locally, e.g. `new \SoapClient('Service.wsdl', ...)`.

Comment: @Olivier how would I store it locally?

Comment: Just manually download the file and copy it in the same directory as your script.

Comment: When I try to save as xml won't load

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use an array to pass parameters, and then wrap that array in another array for the call. Try this:

```
 $params = [
     'username' => 'username',
     'password' => 'password',
     'applicationName' => 'testing',
 ]
 $result =  $client->__soapCall('GetAuthenticationToken', [$params]);
 dd($result);
```

Please let us now if it works since I can't test it for lack of 'real' URLs.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve my issue.  I do think you are right though, that is the format the call should be in.